# No options appear when you paste a picture inside drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I paste an image or icon into the folder drawable Default choices do not appear Like : xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi or mdpi  look at the picture :
[image]
I used the same method in previous times but Now these choices do not appear His method was very easy through selections  xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi or mdpi in  popup window But now what will I do? 
I want to import the same icon But in different sizes , It is inside the drawable folder .

I want to show me such a list 
[image]

Comment: Do you  have multiple drawable folders inside res?

Comment: use mipmap for this

Comment: No, I do not have

Comment: So you have to make the folders first .How do you expect such behavior without folders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create all required folder manually.
like hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi etc and then after that options appear.

Answer (score 0):

If u have all folder types(drawable hdpi,drawable mdpi,drawable xhdpi,drawable xxhdpi,drawable xxxhdpi), just copy these folders, in res\  by right click on res folder and just paste, then android studio update drawable folder to new changes.